# Fluent UI datetime picker current date color not changing issue in react

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am working with Fluent UI datetimepicker. I am trying to change color in today. But its not changing default blue color.

[image]

```
const DatetimePickerFileds = (theme) => {
  return mergeStyleSets({
    root: { 
      selectors: { 
       ".dayIsToday":{ "background-color":theme.colors.addovation70Green},  
      },   
    }, 
  });
};



<DatePicker  
 placeholder="Select a date..."
 ariaLabel="Select a date" 
 styles={controlStyleTheme.DateTimePickerStyle}
/>
```

Please give some suggestion to add custom color for this.

[This is my sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-yonath-mmg10q?file=/src/textFiled.js)

Answer (score 0):

I found it my self. You can use this designer tool to create custom theme.

[check this website](https://fabricweb.z5.web.core.windows.net/pr-deploy-site/refs/heads/7.0/theming-designer/index.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`DatePicker` wraps `Calendar Component`. You can use `calendarProps` to modify styles:

```
<DatePicker
  ...
  calendarProps={{
    styles: {
      root: {
        selectors: {
          '.ms-CalendarDay-dayIsToday': { backgroundColor: '#f00!important' }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Codepen working [example](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/zYJameM?editors=0010).